# Estrutura labirinto em C

Tags: c, array

Boas, gostava de fazer um jogo em C "consola" mas estou com uma duvida....
Basicamente a ideia é ter uma personagem que vá avançando num labirinto graças ao utilizador, caso o utilizador escreva "direita" o personagem move para a direita etc..

Imagino que o labirinto seja basicamente uma array bidimensional, e dentro dela seja inserido tudo de zeros e uns, "1" seria paredes e "0" caminhos livres.. (se houver melhores ideias por favor digam)

Até aí imagino que não existe muita dificuldade, mas pergunto, se quiser meter um inventário ao personagem, como faço para que numa determinada casa da array ter lá um objeto? se por exemplo na array mapa[2][3] já estiver lá um 0 "a dizer que é caminho livre", como posso lá inserir um objeto? tipo uma mochila ou qualquer coisa?

Agradeço a sua disposição em ajudar :)

Comment: Bastaria ter um array separado de objetos. Supondo que faca fosse código 1, e escada código 2: `objetos = { {1,9,1},{3,4,1},{3,4,2} }` (tem uma faca na posição [1,9], outra faca na posição [3,4], e nesta última posição também há uma escada. Nada impediria de usar valores diversos para o próprio mapa se preferir. Em vez de zeros e uns, você usa 1 pra parede, 2 pra faca, 4 pra escada, 8 pra monstro, e assim vai. Uma sala de valor 10 tem com certeza um monstro e uma faca.

Comment: Isso me fez lembrar de um jogo chamado Blip que vinha como passatempo dentro do Gerenciador Financeiro Hábil cujas fases seguiam esse mesmo estilo, mas ainda mais simples: # eram paredes, espaços em branco caminhos a seguir, D era porta, W, água e etc.

Comment: hmmm, obrigado pelas respostas, já me deu uma ideia bastante interessante de como fazer :)
No entanto também me aconselharam de aprender sobre "structs" e basicamente sou novo nisto, disseram-me que me ia servir muito, vi um que outro tutorial de como usar, mas não estou a encaixar as structs com o meu projeto, não sei em que me poderia servir usá-las.... alguma ideia?

Comment: @Bacco isso merece uma resposta.

Comment: Lamento, não estou acostumado ao Stack Overflow, mas caso não receba notificação, respondi em baixo do post...

Answer (score 1):

Vamos supor que você use um caractere para representar uma posição no grid, aonde um espaço em branco é um caminho livre e `X` é uma parede e outros objetos são outros caracteres:

```c
const char caminho = ' ';
const char parede  = 'X';
const char mochila = 'm';
const char faca    = 'f';
const char jogador = '+';
const char ouro    = '$';
const char monstro = 'v';
const char chave   = ',';
const char porta   = '#';
```

Você pode representar o labirinto assim:

```c
#define LARGURA 10
#define ALTURA 10

const char[LARGURA][ALTURA + 1] labirinto = {
    "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "X # XfX $X",
    "X X   XvXX",
    "X XXXXX  X",
    "X X      X",
    "X X XXXX X",
    "X X Xm X X",
    "X   XX X X",
    "X+X    X,X",
    "XXXXXXXXXX",
};
```

Este `+ 1` no final é o terminador da string. Esse formato tem a vantagem que você pode desenhar o labirinto na tela percorrendo linhas e apenas dando um `printf` em cada linha:

```c
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ALTURA; i++) {
    printf("%s", labirinto[i]);
}
```

É óbvio, que se você tiver uma forma melhor de desenhar o labirinto (em especial utilizando imagens, e não apenas texto), não há nada que obrigue você a usar o `printf`, você pode usar o método que achar melhor. Mas de qualquer forma isso é útil ao menos para debug.

Provavelmente você não vai querer o labirinto estático ou com tamanho fixo. Talvez então alocação dinâmica de memória seja melhor:

```c
char* labirinto = malloc(sizeof(char) * altura * (largura + 1));
// Gera o labirinto...
// Roda o jogo...
free(labirinto);
```

Isso daí funciona enquanto você puder usar um caractere para representar uma coisa. Se você tiver uma variedade de objetos muito grande, então o melhor a fazer talvez seja usar arrays de ponteiros para algum tipo de estrutura que descreva estes objetos.